# BatchNormalization in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

What is the difference between `tf.nn.batch_normalization` and `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm`? I have checked the documentation but did not understand if one is better than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tf.contrib refers to a high level machine learning API over Tensorflow. So tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm basically acts as a wrapper over tf.nn.batch_normalization making it easier to use but less flexible than the latter. So, depending upon the application you can use whatever fits your needs. For example in case of tf.nn.batch_norm you will have to give a symbolic link to mean and variance tensors by yourself, but tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm will take care of that for you.